# Why is my Dash application not working when running through command prompt?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I downloaded simple Dash Plotly example from the internet, which ran correctly on my computer. I have installed Anaconda, Python 3.7, Dash and Plotly on my Windows 10 PC. I ran it using the command prompt at the directory where I have saved this code. I get a local host address, when I paste and run this address in browser, I get all the graphs.

The same code when I ran through another Windows 10 PC after installing Anaconda, Python 3.7, Dash and Plotly, is not doing anything. When I call the code through command line using `python app.py`, it does nothing. It simply goes to next line on the command prompt. I am really confused. I am also running it with app.run_server(debug=True), but nothing is happening.

I cannot post the error message or any other details in second case because I am not getting any which is making it even more difficult to debug.

```
import json

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2,1,2],
    "y": [1,2,3,4],
    "customdata": [1,2,3,4],
    "fruit": ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"]
})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="fruit", custom_data=["customdata"])

fig.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')

fig.update_traces(marker_size=20)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='basic-interactions',
        figure=fig
    ),

    html.Div(className='row', children=[
        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown("""
                **Hover Data**

                Mouse over values in the graph.
            """),
            html.Pre(id='hover-data', style=styles['pre'])
        ], className='three columns'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown("""
                **Click Data**

                Click on points in the graph.
            """),
            html.Pre(id='click-data', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown("""
                **Selection Data**

                Choose the lasso or rectangle tool in the graph's menu
                bar and then select points in the graph.

                Note that if `layout.clickmode = 'event+select'`, selection data also 
                accumulates (or un-accumulates) selected data if you hold down the shift
                button while clicking.
            """),
            html.Pre(id='selected-data', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown("""
                **Zoom and Relayout Data**

                Click and drag on the graph to zoom or click on the zoom
                buttons in the graph's menu bar.
                Clicking on legend items will also fire
                this event.
            """),
            html.Pre(id='relayout-data', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns')
    ])
])


@app.callback(
    Output('hover-data', 'children'),
    [Input('basic-interactions', 'hoverData')])
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    return json.dumps(hoverData, indent=2)


@app.callback(
    Output('click-data', 'children'),
    [Input('basic-interactions', 'clickData')])
def display_click_data(clickData):
    return json.dumps(clickData, indent=2)


@app.callback(
    Output('selected-data', 'children'),
    [Input('basic-interactions', 'selectedData')])
def display_selected_data(selectedData):
    return json.dumps(selectedData, indent=2)


@app.callback(
    Output('relayout-data', 'children'),
    [Input('basic-interactions', 'relayoutData')])
def display_relayout_data(relayoutData):
    return json.dumps(relayoutData, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```