# Where is app.py installed when using Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

The Plotly documentation says the following regarding Dash:

> Dash is the best way to build analytical apps in Python using Plotly
> figures. To run the app below, run pip install dash, click "Download"
> to get the code and run python app.py.

However, when I type in "python app.py" it says "No such file or directory" at the location of my command prompt.   Since I use Miniconda, I installed the package from conda-forge.  Perhaps an environment variable is not being set with the Anaconda version, but I have not seen anyone else with this issue.

I searched the folder where Dash is installed, but there was no app.py.   It looks like app.py is part of Flask, but running app.py in Flask's folder returned the following error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'Logger' (most likely due to a circular import).
```

I checked and made sure both Dash and Flask are installed.

My problem is similar to: [Dash: Why is my dash application not working when running through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719614/dash-why-is-my-dash-application-not-working-when-running-through-command-prompt), but in that post, running "Python app.py" did nothing instead of saying the file wasn't found.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here. On the page where you read the text you quoted, containing "to run the app below", there should have been a piece of code right below that. It should even include a Download button there, that will download the file `app.py` (if not, paste the code into an empty file called `app.py`). You can then open a command prompt in the directory containing that file and run it via `python app.py`.

So, `app.py` is not a standard command that gets enabled by installing plotly. It's rather the most commonly used name for single-file plotly apps, which you can run by calling them via python, if `Dash` is installed. You could of course rename and call it with the new name, calling it `app.py` is not mandatory.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.  Thank you for the clarification.